# clone / use .ps from another project gitlab

Tags: git, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I need use a few .ps1 from a project to make build and deploy in another. I try this:

repo with the .ps1 (its public and this repo have test2.ps1 and test3.ps1):

https://lgitlabn01vpr.xxx.com/user/test_clone

and this is the repo that needs the script to build and deploy

https://lgitlabn01vpr.xxx.com/mariano_prueba_2

in "mariano_prueba_2" i have:

dockerfile:

```
FROM registryn01vpr.xxx.com/devops/windows_containers/iis_images/iis10_net4_5_ora12_2:latest

SHELL [ "powershell" ]

COPY example/test3.ps1 c:/


EXPOSE 80
```

this mis my gitlab-ci.yml:

```
image: docker:latest

stages:
 - initialize
 - build
 - deploy


repo1 pull:
 stage: initialize
 script:
   - git clone https://lgitlabn01vpr.xxx.com/user/test_clone.git

variables:
  DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay2

services:
  - docker:dind
cache:
    key: "$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME"
    untracked: true

before_script:
 - docker login -u $CI_REGISTRY_USER -p $CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD $CI_REGISTRY


build-master:
 stage: build
 script:
   - cp test_clone/ example/
   - docker build --cache-from "$CI_REGISTRY/$CI_PROJECT_PATH/$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH" -t "$CI_REGISTRY/$CI_PROJECT_PATH/$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH" .
   - docker push "$CI_REGISTRY/$CI_PROJECT_PATH/$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH"
 

deploy-to-swarm-develop:
 stage: deploy
 when: manual
 variables:
   DOCKER_HOST: "$CI_DOCKER_HOST_TEST"
   SERVICE_NAME: "$CI_PROJECT_NAME"
   CI_CARPETAS_PASSWD: "$CI_CARPETAS_PASSWD"
   CI_CARPETAS_USER: "$CI_CARPETAS_USER"
 image: docker:latest
2  script:
   - powershell -File test2.ps1 ${CI_CARPETAS_USER} ${CI_CARPETAS_PASSWD}
   - docker stack deploy --with-registry-auth --compose-file=docker-stack-compose-test.yml ${SERVICE_NAME}
 environment:
   name: develop
   url: http://${CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME}.xxx.com
```

When i try with this , in the build stage say dont exist "example/test3.ps1".

Someone can help me with this or recommend another way?

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All stages are independent of each other by default. This means you can not automatically rely on some output of the previous stage. You need to manually tell GitLab CI that it should hand over those `artifacts`. see https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#artifacts

in your case i would assume that the next lines would fix this.

```
repo1 pull:
 stage: initialize
 script:
   - git clone https://lgitlabn01vpr.xxx.com/user/test_clone.git
 artifacts:
   paths:
     - test_clone
```

This should make the `test_clone` directory available within your sub projects.

Additionally you could also take a look at `git submodules` which is a perfect fit for this case :)